# Javascript replaces didn't work

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I'm trying to replace a part of my HTML code with JS but doesn't work.

I have the next code:

```
<td id="one"><a href="servlet.jsp?account='old'" >old</a></td>
```

And i'm want to change "old" for "new", like this:

```
<td id="one"><a href="servlet.jsp?account='new'" >new</a></td>
```

Then i'm using JS because i need to do with this using the method replace(), then, my JS is:

```
var old = "old";
var rep = "new";
var elem = document.getElementById("one");
var text = elem.innerHTML;
text = text.replace(old,rep);
elem.innerHTML = text;
```

I tryed and search but always i founded the same.

Any suggestion are welcome.

(I wrote the cody by memory because i'm not in the office and it's more complex) i'll try tomorrow)

Comment: Why are you using quotes in you GET argument values? Besides that, please **never** use string operations to modify DOM elements.

Comment: Why are you using replace instead of just overwriting?

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token new`. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: Using `elem`, get the child `<a>` element, and use `replace` on its `href` property instead. You shouldn't have to reset the `innerHTML` of its parent

Comment: I wrote the cody by memory because i'm not in the office and it's more complex i'll try tomorrow
"new" var i didn't used it's a example only for tell tthis.

Answer (score 7):

Because "new" is a reserved word in JavaScript.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: ... which throws a syntax error and hence the code is not even executed.

Answer (score -1):

No clue - it works for me. However, your method is very insecure; instead of working on `elem.innerHTML`, it would be much better to use `elem.getAttribute` and `elem.setAttribute` for direct access to `href`. Otherwise, imagine what would happen if your `old` happens to be `"ref"`, or something similar that coincidentally exists before your intended term...

EDIT: doh, didn't even notice the var name >.<